# Parsing DateTime object to string in Doctrine's query builder

Tags: doctrine, symfony4, query-builder

I'm writing application in Symfony 4 framework. I have entities which looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use DateTime;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CompanyRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Company
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $taxNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $street;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $postalCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     */
    private $officeId;

    /**
     * @var datetime $created
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable = false)
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var datetime $updated
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable = false)
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Employee", mappedBy="company")
     */
    private $employees;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\AuditCompany", mappedBy="company")
     */
    private $companyAudits;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->employees = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->companyAudits = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Gets triggered only on insert
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function onPrePersist()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new DateTime("now");
        $this->updatedAt = new DateTime("now");
    }

    /**
     * Gets triggered every time on update
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function onPreUpdate()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new DateTime("now");
    }

    public function setId($id): self
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(?string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTaxNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->taxNumber;
    }

    public function setTaxNumber(string $taxNumber): self
    {
        $this->taxNumber = $taxNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStreet(): ?string
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    public function setStreet(?string $street): self
    {
        $this->street = $street;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setCity(string $city): self
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPostalCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->postalCode;
    }

    public function setPostalCode(string $postalCode): self
    {
        $this->postalCode = $postalCode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOfficeId(): ?string
    {
        return $this->officeId;
    }

    public function setOfficeId(string $officeId): self
    {
        $this->officeId = $officeId;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): string
    {
        return $this->createdAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s O');
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(DateTime $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): string
    {
        return $this->updatedAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s O');
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(DateTime $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Employee[]
     */
    public function getEmployees(): Collection
    {
        return $this->employees;
    }

    public function addEmployee(Employee $employee): self
    {
        if (!$this->employees->contains($employee)) {
            $this->employees[] = $employee;
            $employee->setCompany($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEmployee(Employee $employee): self
    {
        if ($this->employees->contains($employee)) {
            $this->employees->removeElement($employee);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($employee->getCompany() === $this) {
                $employee->setCompany(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|AuditCompany[]
     */
    public function getCompanyAudits(): Collection
    {
        return $this->companyAudits;
    }

    public function addCompanyAudit(AuditCompany $companyAudit): self
    {
        if (!$this->companyAudits->contains($companyAudit)) {
            $this->companyAudits[] = $companyAudit;
            $companyAudit->setCompany($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCompanyAudit(AuditCompany $companyAudit): self
    {
        if ($this->companyAudits->contains($companyAudit)) {
            $this->companyAudits->removeElement($companyAudit);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($companyAudit->getCompany() === $this) {
                $companyAudit->setCompany(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I'm getting company by id by query builder tools. I'm doing it by methods:

```
public function find($id){
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('c')
            ->addSelect('ca')
            ->addSelect('partial aud.{id, name, status, version}')
            ->addSelect('e')
            ->leftJoin('c.companyAudits','ca')
            ->leftJoin('ca.audit', 'aud')
            ->leftJoin('c.employees', 'e')
            ->where('c.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id',$id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult()[0];
    }
```

Main problem is with Dates createdAt and updatedAt. Result of queries is like below:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Auto serwis",
    "taxNumber": "PL831231231",
    "street": "Sienkiewicza",
    "city": "Warsaw",
    "postalCode": "55-232",
    "officeId": 11,
    "createdAt": {
        "date": "2019-09-13 10:55:19.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "date": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
    }
}
```

The problem is I'd like to obtain string value of createdAt and updatedAt, not object like in above response. I have getter method for createdAt and updatedAt, which return formated string:

```
public function getCreatedAt(): string
    {
        return $this->createdAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s O');
    }
```

I'd like to obtain Dates in the same string format. How should I do it? I would be grateful for help.
Best regards.

Comment: try getScalarResult() instead of getArrayResult()

Comment: The result is very similar: "a_updatedAt": {
            "date": "2019-07-16 14:35:01.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
        },

Comment: How do you get that result, with `json_encode($repository->find($id))`? Please add your code for this step.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#using-callbacks-to-serialize-properties-with-object-instances

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
->getQuery()
->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR)
```

or simply

```
->getQuery()
->getResult(3)
```

In this case, the results are returned without any special format like a simple PHP query, but in "getArrayResult" the results are "array serialized"

Therefore, the datetime object is also "serialized"

Comment: Why though? Also what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Why did you put this into a comment? Wouldn't it be better if you put the explanation into the answer and we deleted our comments?